# Remove Non-SVG Slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have code for a slider:

```
var slider = d3.select('body').append('p').text('Sent or Received Threshold: ');

slider.append('label')
    .attr('for', 'threshold')
    .text('');

slider.append('input')
    .attr('type', 'range')
    .attr('min', d3.min(graph.links, function(d) {return d.value; }))
    .attr('max', d3.max(graph.links, function(d) {return d.value; }))
    .attr('value', d3.min(graph.links, function(d) {return d.value; }))
    .attr('id', 'threshold')
    .style('width', '100%')
    .style('display', 'block')
    .on('input', function () {
        var threshold = this.value;

        d3.select('label').text(threshold);

        var newData = [];
        graph.links.forEach( function (d) {
            if (d.value >= threshold) {newData.push(d); };
        });

  color.domain([d3.min(newData, function(d) {return d.value; }), d3.max(newData, function(d) {return d.value; })]).interpolator(d3.interpolateBlues);

        link = link.data(newData, function(d){ return d.value});
        link.exit().remove();
        var linkEnter = link.enter().append("path")
                      .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.value); })
                      .style("fill", "none")
                      .style("stroke-width", "3px");
        link = linkEnter.merge(link).style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.value); });

        node = node.data(graph.nodes);

        simulation.nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on('tick', tick)
        simulation.force("link")
    .links(newData);

        simulation.alphaTarget(0.1).restart();

    });
```

I would like to remove the slider within a change function based on a PHP drop-down. For the d3 viz itself, I use `d3.selectAll("svg > *").remove()`. I know this slider isn't part of SVG, so how would I remove it? Currently, on change of the drop-down, a new slider is added below the previous slider. Is there a `d3.selectAll` statement that needs to be placed somewhere?

Thank you for any insight you all might have!

Comment: Gerardo - not sure why you removed your comment, but it was spot on. Thank you very much - that helped me understand d3 remove beyond just this example.

Comment: I removed it because I'm writing it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

D3 is not restricted to manipulating SVG elements. In fact, D3 can manipulate anything in that page.

That being said, you can do that by simply using:

```
selection.remove()
```

Where `selection` is, of course, any selection containing the slider.

For instance, you can select by element...

```
d3.select("input").remove();
```

... or by ID:

```
d3.select("#threshold").remove();
```

But, in your case, the simplest solution is using the selection you **already have**:

```
slider.remove();
```

Here is a demo with your code for the slider, click the button:

```js
var slider = d3.select('body').append('p').text('Sent or Received Threshold: ');

slider.append('label')
    .attr('for', 'threshold')
    .text('');

slider.append('input')
    .attr('type', 'range')
    .attr('min', 0)
    .attr('max', 100)
    .attr('value', 30)
    .attr('id', 'threshold')
    .style('width', '100%')
    .style('display', 'block');
    
d3.select("button").on("click", function(){
    slider.remove();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
```